# Is it OK to have a preliminary study as its own chapter in a PhD thesis?

Tags: phd, thesis

My PhD thesis has the following structure.

- Introduction [5 pages]
- Lit Review [50 pages]
- Project 1: Preliminary study [25 pages]
- Project 1: Extended study [30 pages]
- Project 2: Preliminary study [25 pages]
- Project 2: Extended study [30 pages]
- Conclusion + outlook [10 pages]

Is it OK to have a preliminary study as its own chapter?

Comment: why do you already know the number of pages?

Answer (score 2):

While this is really a question for your advisor, I'd suggest, contrary to the [answer of tschwarz](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/185769/75368), that this is fine. If the preliminary study for the second project gave you important insights that led to the extended study then, yes, present it that way.

It might be important, even necessary, to do so if the parameters needed to be changed for the extended study.

But, run this by your advisor who hopefully has better knowledge of the work as a whole.

Comment: I agree because so many programs undertaken are not sure to produce worthwhile data and the final direction (and title of ultimate thesis) cannot be determined. It's common enough in some science/eng PhDs to have a title like: *Studies In XXXXXXXX*. Here if the two studies ultimately pursued by OP were related they could be grouped into a single chapter; likewise with the extended studies - though naturally in separate sections.

Answer (score -1):

You definitely should not call it "Preliminary Study". An introductary chapter could make a lot of sense. Having topics in a two chapter sequence looks a bit odd. Since you do not tell us how you understand the difference between preliminary and extended study, it is hard to come up with better names. However, having a thesis with five chapters is just as OK as having one with seven. You just need to structure your material in a way that makes sense.